# Symfony Rest architecture

Tags: php, rest, symfony, architecture

We are building an application with Symfony, most of our logic is inside Rest Api methods because we are going to have Android and IOS apps.
[image: App architecture]

Our functions are something like this:

```
public function postEmployeeAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
```

We are using FOSRestController, and we get the paremeters using paramfetcher. It is clear how to get and post information from the ios and android apps. The question is how do we call the rest services from within the Symfony app. If a controller needs to insert an employee, does it have to make a rest request to the logic using localhost or the ip?. 
It seems very complicated and unnecessary since it has to generate an authentication token.
We thought of duplicating all the functions into normal controllers, but I don't think duplicating code is a good idea. We also considered calling the rest functions as normal functions but apparently is really hard to create a ParamFetcher object.

If any one has an idea of how to have Rest Api methods and how calle them from the outside and from inside the app in an easy way, it would be great.

Comment: I prefer to separate the web app into an app on its own. So you have a web app, mobile app(s), etc that consume a public facing rest api. With the project structure you have (mixed web app / api) you will face some challenges in separating out the api without getting to a point where it's "annoying" to use the api in the web app.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, also because there will be a mix up with the ports since the web app port lets say 80 will have to listen for requests it won't be available for the rest call if the user is waiting for the response, and we would have to create two instances anyway. The problem with this solution is that we already started and we would like to move as little code as possible, but I think we are going to have to do this in the future